# Prove that the following statements are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

So I have three matrices A,B and C with conditions as outlined below.
I need to prove the four statements are equivalent by proving if and only
if between each of them.

I struggle to understand how should I set up this problem
and prove the statements consequently?

[image]

Comment: As a side note, you could shorten the overall length of the proof by proving $(i)\Rightarrow (ii)\Rightarrow (iii)\Rightarrow (iv)\Rightarrow (i)$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

(i) The linear equations have no solutions
A matrix can only have 3 possiblities for solutions

- 0 solutions
- 1 solution
- Infinitely many solutions

A matrix having no solutions means that the augmented matrix looks like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
num1 ... numN & | & sum1 \\
............. & | & .... \\
0 ..........0 & | & sumM
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This means that the rank of teh augmented matrix (i.e. A) is greater than teh coefficient matrix (i.e. B) (This is important later).

So this means that if you split up your matrix into vectors, where each vector represents a column of A, it would look like
x1$\begin{bmatrix} num1 \\ ... \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ + ... +
x2$\begin{bmatrix} numN \\ ... \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} sum1 \\ ... \\ sumM \end{bmatrix}$

As you can see, teh last row of the vectors can't add up to sumM because they are all zeros. Therefore, the last column can't be written as a linear combination of the vectors in the first n columns

It's pretty intuitive that if teh last columns (which is the column that everything is supposed to add up to) can't be written as a linear combination of teh first n vectors, there there would be no solution to

x1$\begin{bmatrix} num11 \\ ... \\ num1N \end{bmatrix}$ + ... +
x2$\begin{bmatrix} numN1 \\ ... \\ numNM \end{bmatrix}$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} sum1 \\ ... \\ sumM \end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, putting this all in an augmented matrix will have no solutions. And we have proven (i) <-> (ii)

See if you can do the rest.